# Should I use Response.Write directly from a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have been trying to avoid using Response.Write(...) directly in my MVC Views. The reason being that I just need to type the string literals and the view engine knows what to do. However, in certain circumstances I seem to be creating way too many pointy brackets (<% %>). So, which of these 2 code snippets do you find more acceptable?

```
<% if (true)
{
  Response.Write(Model.SomeValue);
} %>
```

Or

```
<% if (true) { %>
<%= Model.SomeValue %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Html.Encode( Model.SomeValue )`

Comment: @tvanfosson:  Why is it Html.Encode( Model.SomeValue )?

Comment: Assuming `Model.SomeValue` originated from user input, `Html.Encode()`, `<%:`, or Razor's `@` is generally required to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

Answer (score 4):

This is why Html Helpers exist (to avoid spaghetti code as much as possible):

```
<%= Html.MySuperHelper(Model.SomeValue) %>
```

Every time you need write an `if` statement in a view you might ask yourself the question: wouldn't it be better to write a helper method (which as a bonus could be unit tested) instead?

Answer (score 2):

How about a third possibility?

```
<%= condition ? Html.Encode(Model.SomeValue) : "" %>
```

Although in practice you should keep all but the very simplest logic out of your view altogether. Either do the work in your controller or wrap the logic up in a HTML helper of some kind.

Comment: I'd use `Html.Encode( Model.SomeValue )`, if the property is not a value type.

Answer (score 0):

Or a fourth:

`<%= condition ? Html.Encode(Model.SomeValue) : "" %>`